# Vim global command to make each line containing a symbol, start with a word

Tags: vim, global

Consider following text file:

```
something
something
something = someother thing
other thing = third thing
another thing = forth thing
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
something
something
keyword something = someother thing
keyword other thing = third thing
keyword another thing = forth thing
```

so that, I add keyword to each line, what is contains a equals symbol in it.
Can I do this with global command, or how do you recommend I should do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:g/=/s/^/keyword /
```

or

```
:g/=/normal ikeyword
```

Note the space after "keyword"

For this type of problem, it's also quite common to use a solution like:

```
:%!sed '/=/s/^/keyword /'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to accomplish.  Your title suggests a common pattern, but I don't see one in your example.  So I'll show you both.

#### Making Changes Among Things With A Common Pattern

You can do search and replace with the following:

```
:s/<regex you are searching for>/<string to replace with>/g
```

`s/pattern/replacement/` does search & replace, and the extra g will propogate the changes

#### Multi-Line Edit

Vim also lets you edit multiple lines at once.  Say you want to edit the following three lines:

```
something = someother thing
other thing = third thing
another thing = fourth thing
```

1. Put your cursor on the `s` at the first `something` line.
   Press `<ctrl>-v` outside of insert mode to go into Visual mode.`
2. Scroll down to the `a` on the bottom line.  All three starting characters of all 3 lines should be highlighted.
3. Press `A` to append or `I` to enter directly into insert mode and start typing.  When you hit escape your changes should reflect!  You can also do other commands like `y` and `d`, etc.

Comment: What I was looking for was exactly what William Pursell suggested. That command insert a keyword to each line in a file, that contains an equals symbol in it.